# Differences between distinct objects into indistinguishable boxes and the inverse.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I had 10 balls that I would like to put into 5 boxes.

If the balls were each distinctly numbered from 1-10 and the boxes
are indistinguishable, then there are $5^{10}$ ways of doing so.

Now for the inverse. If the balls were indistinguishable from each other and
each box is distinctly numbered 1-5, then the number of ways to distribute the balls
is the number of non-negative solutions to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +x_4+x_5 = 10,\\ 0\leq x_i \leq10$$

What I'm confused about is why isn't it the case that the number of ways to do the latter is $5^{10}$ ways. I'm looking for an intuitive explanation if possible but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out the following websites,

https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-identical-bins/ and https://brilliant.org/wiki/identical-objects-into-distinct-bins/